# Как по найденному значению в сроке сделать изменение в другой строке

Tags: python

есть строки:

```
n = 'babab'
m = 'metot'
```

желаемый результат: `new_str = 'MeToT'`

то есть, если найдена буква `'b'` в первой строке, на этом же месте в строке `m` буква должна увеличить регистр.

```
new_str = (m[0].upper() + m[1] + m[2].upper() + m[3] + m[4].upper())
```

-- так не подходит, так как места 'b' зависят от введенного текста пользователем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = 'metot'
n = 'babab'
new_str = ''
for i in range(len(m)):
    new_str += m[i].upper() if n[i] == 'b' else m[i]
print(new_str)
```

Comment: `new_str+=` может к квадратичному вместо линейного O(n) времени исполнения  вести.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> ''.join([a.upper() if b == 'b' else a for a, b in zip('metot', 'babab')])
'MeToT'
```

Если данные в numpy массивах:

```
>>> a[b==b'b'[0]] &= 0x5f # upper mask
>>> a.tostring()
b'MeToT'
```

где `a` к примеру:

```
>>> numpy.frombuffer(b'metot', dtype=numpy.uint8)
array([109, 101, 116, 111, 116], dtype=uint8)
```

Если входные символы в ascii диапазоне, это может быть заметно быстрее для больших строк.

Answer (score 2):

Вот примитивное и наверняка не самое эффективное решение:

```
In [77]: new_str = ''.join([m[i] if c!='b' else m[i].upper() for i,c in enumerate(n)])

In [78]: new_str
Out[78]: 'MeToT'
```

решение с использованием [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) + [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [86]: from itertools import starmap

In [87]: ''.join(starmap(lambda x,y: y if x!='b' else y.upper(), zip(n,m)))
Out[87]: 'MeToT'
```

Comment: Если приходится lambda заводить, то  [лучше list comprehension использовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629683/23044) вместо map + lambda.

Comment: @jfs, согласен. первое решение использует `list comprehension`, а во втором я решил "поиграться" с новой для себя функцией ;)

Comment: Если поиграться, то map уже поддерживает несколько аргументов: `''.join(map(lambda x,y: y if x!='b' else y.upper(), 'babab', 'metot'))`

Comment: @jfs, не знал, спасибо